# Can I avoid using a public IP on Block-Producer (BP) node?

Tags: stake-pool, security, network, topology

My BP and relays are on the same local subnet, I would prefer to give them the private IP address in the topology files.

However, all of the guides I've come across explicitly state using public IPs. Is there a problem with using private IPs in the topology files to connect my BP node and my relay nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your Cardano nodes needs a static IP address to communicate between each other. You can use IP or domain names.

**Block Producer (BP) node**

For better security, you can choose to set a private IP to your BP node to communicate with your relays (on the same private network) since your BP is hosting sensitive data you don't really want to expose.

**Relay nodes**

However, it is necessary that the relay nodes have a public IP address as the other external relay servers will need to establish incoming TCP/IP connections with yours to exchange and update informations.

You can set 1 public IP address for each one of your relays but you can also use a single public IP address and port-forward to share with your relays.

Comment: Hi @Bao, thank you for the feedback. I guess I was wondering why I would ever use the BP's public IP if I didn't need to, and I don't really see a need to.

Comment: As long as your BP can communicate with your relays, it is not required to have a public IP address on your BP. But your relays will need at least 1 public IP to receive incoming TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Great that’s all I need to hear, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you manage your nodes :)
but for security reasons, i would recommend to use another node, which will be the "Jump-Server".

this Jump-Server has a public_IP, which will be used for you to connect with ssh, and only this system will have access to connect with ssh to the rest of your nodes (BP and Relays)